# Xamarin Forms In the .FSI -> Can't find NetStandard

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, f#-interactive

I am using Visual Studio for the Mac and I want to test out some of my ideas in a script file.  When I try and add a reference to Xamarin Forms in the script, the netstandard assembly can't be located.

For example

```
#r "/packages/Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.482510/lib/netstandard2.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll"

type Hex(tile: Tile) = 
    inherit Frame()
    member this.Tile = tile
```

> The type "object" is required here and is unavailable.  You must and a
>   reference to assembly .netstandard Version 2.0.0.0

The thing is, I can't find where that would be on my local file system and just doing this

```
#r "NETStandard.Library.dll"
```

does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this is not the best way, but I went into the Finder, Hit Go -> Computer and put "net standard" in the search bar.  Lots of hits came back so I just picked an arbitrary net standard.dll and selected "copy path" which I pasted into the fsi.  It works, but I want to take a shower now....